# Histogram not plotting RandomVariate of EmpiricalDistribution

Tags: bugs, probability-or-statistics, distributions, histograms, windows

**Bug introduced in 11.1 or earlier and fixed in 11.2**

---

I have a seemingly odd case in 11.1 where a sample from an `EmpiricalDistribution` is not being plotted by `Histogram` but the same sample is plotted by `SmoothHistogram`.

The `weights` and `values` are

```
{weights, values} ={{1.00875,1.99112,1.99116,1.95452,1.92082,1.87752,1.84808,1.78201,1.7213,1.6468,1.58059,1.50983,1.43815,1.36926,1.31043,1.26065,1.22202,1.18499,1.15066,1.12557,1.10673,1.09089,1.07963,1.06488,1.05452,1.04687,1.03911,1.03402,1.02988,1.02755,1.02153,1.01821,1.01406,1.01201,1.00763,1.00593,1.00405,1.00396,1.00296,1.00295,1.00108,1.00108,1.00108,1.0011,1.0011,1.0011,1.00031,1.00031,1.00031,1.00031,1.00031,1.00031,1.00031,1.00031,1.00031,1.00031,1.00031,1.00031,1.00031,1.00031,1.00031,1.00031,1.00031,1.00031,1.00031,1.00031,1.00031,0.999535,0.999535,0.999535,0.999535,0.999535,0.999535,0.999535,0.999535,0.999535,0.999535,0.999535,0.999535,0.999535,0.999535,0.999535,0.999535,0.999535,0.998749,0.998749,0.998749,0.998749,0.998749,1.,1.,1.,1.},{3,6,9,12,15,18,21,24,27,30,33,36,39,42,45,48,51,54,57,60,63,66,69,72,75,78,81,84,87,90,93,96,99,102,105,108,111,114,117,120,123,126,129,132,135,138,141,144,147,150,153,156,159,162,165,168,171,174,177,180,183,186,189,192,195,198,201,204,207,210,213,216,219,222,225,228,231,234,237,240,243,246,249,252,255,258,261,264,267,270,273,276,279}};
```

I setup the distribution as

```
ed = EmpiricalDistribution[(weights - Min@weights) -> values];
data = RandomVariate[ed, 100000];
```

`SmoothHistogram` has no issues plotting this.

```
SmoothHistogram[data, PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

However `Histogram` runs forever until I abort it.

```
Histogram[data]
```

> ```
> $Aborted
> ```

Any ideas what is going on here?
Version 11.1 on Win 7 Ent.

---

CASE:3879575

Comment: Works like a charm on my machine (Mac OS, Mathematica 11.0.1): (https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhWfM.png) Probably a memory issue or something like that.

Comment: I can confirm this for 11.1 on Win 10 (64 bit).

Comment: Has been reported to WRI.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems to be related to the way the *binning* is determined by [`Histogram`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Histogram.html) if no explicit *bspec* is given. Once *bspecs* are given it seems to work without any problem:

```
Histogram[ data, {0, 95, 5} ]
```

[image: Histogram of the data]

I would assume that somewhere inside the assumption of smoothly distributed data is violated and causes the algorithm to get stuck. Note for example that it works out correctly when we add a small amount to the shifted (standardized) weights:

```
edMod = EmpiricalDistribution[ 
    0.001 + Standardize[ weights, (*shift*) Min, (*scale*) Function[1] ] -> values 
];

dataMod = RandomVariate[ edMod, 100000 ];

Histogram @ data
```

[image: Histogram of the modified data]

So there may be *precision issues* here. But to me the behavior looks like a bug.

Comment: Good workaround. (+1)